# Apache Lucene - Spell Checker Dictionary

Tags: apache, dictionary, lucene, spell-checking

I have built a Spell Checker application using Apache Lucene. I'm currently using a dictionary in the form on a text file with English words (one per line). My Spell Checker is being used on an online Tech forum, so I need a replacement dictionary that has some Tech words in the same format. I've searched but I cannot find any. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The professional societies for the domain in question will likely have dictionaries. Once you have a dictionary with the appropriate tech words, you can create a temporary file with both sets of words, then sort that file to create a file with all of the words in sorted order. (On Linux or with Cygwin, you could use the 'sort' command for the sorting.)